# Netlogo making a list out of itself for a given length

Tags: list, netlogo

I want to create a list out of its own values for a given length.

For example, given the list `[0 1]` and a desired list length of 7, the output would be `[0 1 0 1 0 1 0]`. The length is defined by `population`, and is defined by a slider. I declared the variable `x` that should iterate through the list. If the length of the list is shorter than the value of `population` it should be set to `0` again.

I tried it with a loop command but it runs infinitely:

```
let x 0
  loop[
    if length exp-dif-li <= population[
      ifelse x < length exp-dif-li[
        set x 0]
      [ set exp-dif-li lput item x exp-dif-li exp-dif-li
        set x x + 1]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mod`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#mod) and [`n-values`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-values) are your friends here:

```
to-report continue-list [ lst n ]
  report n-values n [ item (? mod length lst) lst ]
end
```

Example uses:

```
observer> show continue-list [0 1] 7
observer: [0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
observer> show continue-list [0 1] 1
observer: [0]
observer> show continue-list [0 1 2 3 4] 22
observer: [0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1]
```

Edit: Realized it would be good to talk about why this works! `n-values n [ ... ]` creates a list of length `n` by sending the numbers `0` through  `n - 1` to the given reporter. The reporter accesses the number with `?` (this is the NetLogo [task](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks) syntax). So we want to keep repeating the items in the original list. A really good function for repeatedly cycling through numbers is `mod`. In general, item `i` of the new list should be item `i mod <length of original list>`. So, putting that together, `n-values n [ item (? mod length lst) lst ]` creates a new list of length `n` by repeating the items from the list `lst` as necessary.

Comment: If anyone wanted the list to be randomized, you can use the shuffle command in between report and n-values

Answer (score 1):

To get out of a loop you need to call end or stop.

inserting the line

```
if length exp-dif-li = 7 [stop]
```

the right place would do it. Loop can very easily turn into a infinite loop and a freeze so it is best avoided.

I prefer while loops. they are safer and less prone to infinite loops which would look like this

```
while length exp-dif-li < 7
  [
   if length exp-dif-li <= population[
  ifelse x < length exp-dif-li[
    set x 0]
  [ set exp-dif-li lput item x exp-dif-li exp-dif-li
    set x x + 1]
  ]
```

Netlogo has another method which I have not seen elsewhere and is very robust against infinite loops. [repeat] the usage in you case would seem to be

```
  repeat 7  [
            if length exp-dif-li <= population[
             ifelse x < length exp-dif-li[set x 0]
             [ set exp-dif-li lput item x exp-dif-li exp-dif-li
            set x x + 1]
            ]
```